# Regex matching list of emoticons of various type

Tags: javascript, regex, emoticons

I need to create a faunctionality, that will allow me to parse a text looking for a match for emoticon string in different format. It can be either a `:)` type emoticon, or a `&lt;dog&gt;` (`<dog>`) type.
Currently my function can find both types but needs two different regexes for this task, and I'd like to make it in just one step. Any ideas ?

Live example at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rmQSx/5/

and the code :

```
function replaceEmoticons(text) {
    var emots1 = {
        ':)': 'smile.gif',
        ':(': 'sad.gif',
    },
    emots2 = {
        '&lt;dog&gt;': 'dog.gif',
        '&lt;fly&gt;': 'fly.gif'   
    },
    regex1,regex2,p,re;


    for(p in emots1){
        regex1 = "["+p+"]{2}";
        re = new RegExp(regex1, "g");

        text = text.replace(re, function (match) {
            return typeof emots1[match] != 'undefined' ?
                '<img src="'+emots1[match]+'"/>' :
                match;
        });
    }

    for(p in emots2){
        regex2 = "("+p+")(|$)";
        re = new RegExp(regex2, "g");

        text = text.replace(re, function(match) {
            return typeof emots2[match] != 'undefined' ?
                '<img src="'+emots2[match]+'"/>' :
                match;
        });
    }

     return text;   
}

console.log(replaceEmoticons('this is &lt;dog&gt;b a&lt;fly&gt; simple test :) , ;)   and more:):('));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need the funny stuff you do at the beginning of each `for` loop to modify the regex.  Get rid of that, and there's nothing stopping you from merging the two sets together.

However, you *should* escape the special characters `(` and `)` in your smileys when making the regexes.  Also, I would suggest making the regex search case-insensitive so that `<dog>` and `<DOG>` are both matched.

```
//helper function to escape special characters in regex
function RegExpEscape(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"); 
}

function replaceEmoticons(text) {   
    var emots = {
        ':)'         : 'smile.gif',
        ':('         : 'sad.gif',
        '&lt;dog&gt;': 'dog.gif',
        '&lt;fly&gt;': 'fly.gif'
    }

    var result = text;
    var emotcode;
    var regex;

    for (emotcode in emots)
    {
        regex = new RegExp(RegExpEscape(emotcode), 'gi');
        result = result.replace(regex, function(match) {
            var pic = emots[match.toLowerCase()];

            if (pic != undefined) {
                return '<img src="' + pic + '"/>';
                    } else {
                return match;
                    }
                });
    }

    return result;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use |

you could do something like:

```
re = new RegExp(smiley1|smiley2|...|smileyN);
```