# Javascript Regex to match emoticon symbols in my array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, symbols, emoticons

I have this array that has emo symbols and associated image files for each emo path.

[**Working demo of my code on JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/3183/)

But using this code, only :) this emo returns the correct smile.png image but rest of the emo are not working.

How do I write the correct regex that match each of these symbols and choose the appropriate file for each emo ?

```
 //Replace Emo with images
  function replaceEmoticons(text) {
  var emoticons = {
    ':)' : 'smile.png',
    ': )' : 'smile.png',
    ':D' : 'laugh.png',
    ':->' : 'laugh.png',
    ':d' : 'laugh-sm.png',
    ':-)': 'smile-simple.png',
    ':p': 'tounge.png',
    ':P': 'tounge-lg.png',
    ': P': 'tng1.png',
    '>-)': 'evil.png',
    ':(': 'sad.png',
    ':-(': 'sadd.png',
    ':-<': 'sadd.png',
    ':-O': 'surprise.png',
    ':O': 'sur2.png',
    ':o': 'sur3.png',
    ':-o': 'sur3.png',
    ':-*': 'kiss.png',
    ':*': 'kiss.png',
    ':-@': 'angry.png',
    ':@': 'angry.png',
    ':$': 'con2.png',
    ':-$': 'con1.png',
    'O.o': 'con2.png',
    'o.O': 'con2.png',
    ':/': 'weird.png',
    ':x': 'x.png',
    ':X': 'x.png',
    ':!': 's.png',
    '(:I': 'egg.png',
    '^.^': 'kit.png',
    '^_^': 'kit.png',
    ';)': 'wink.png',
    ';-)': 'wink.png',
    ":')": 'hc.png',
    ":'(": 'cry.png',
    "|-O": 'yawn.png',
    "-_-": 'poke.png',
    ":|": 'p1.png',
    "$_$": 'he.png'

  }, url = "images/emo/";
  // a simple regex to match the characters used in the emoticons
  return text.replace(/[:\-)D]+/g, function (match) {

    return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?
           '<img class="emo" src="'+url+emoticons[match]+'"/>' :
           match;
  });
}


replaceEmoticons("Hi this is a test string :) with all :P emos working :D");
```

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077049/regex-matching-emoticons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077049/regex-matching-) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317299/regex-matching-list-of-emoticons-of-various-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317299/regex-matching-list-of-emoticons-of-various-type)

Answer (score 2):

This regex:

```
 [:\-)D]+
```

Does not match many of the emoticons in your list.  Any character other than `:`, `\`, `-`, `)`,or `D` will prevent it from being recognized.

If you have a list of strings you want to match, you can easily build a regex to match any of them (and nothing else) by escaping each one and joining them together with `|`.  Something like this:

```
// given a string, return the source for a regular expression that will 
// match only that exact string, by escaping any regex metacharacters
// contained within.
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

// build a regex that will match all the emoticons. Written out, it looks
// like this:   /:\)|: \)|:D|:->|:d|:-\)|:p|:P|..../g
var emoticonRegex = 
  new RegExp(Object.keys(emoticons).map(RegExp.escape).join('|'), 'g');
```

Then use that in place of your literal regex:

```
return text.replace(emoticonRegex, function (match) { ...
```

Comment: But HOW can OP write a regex? (I believe that's the question the OP asks).

Comment: I was getting to that part, @cale_b. :)

Comment: Well I have been able to write all the symbols of emos in my string and that seems to work. Can anyone explain me how regex works? Does it take the combo of each and every character inside? this is working for me i just dont understand how this works text.replace(/[:;\-)DPp(oO|><*!']+/g, function (match)

Comment: Thanks but I am just using single occurce of each character in my regex without escaping or joing anything with pipe sign and that also seems to work. Does my method has any other bad implication? Will it treat simple text messages as emo ? or it is fine to use my way .. this way works for me return text.replace(/[:^;\-)DPp(oO|><*!'-@._d]+/g, function (match) {

Comment: Your solution matches all of the emoticons, but it will also match combinations of those characters that *don't* appear in the list - for example, any number of colons, hyphens, or periods in a row: `::`, `---`, `...` all match.  Heck, even a single parenthesis in a sentence will match. And when it finds a match that doesn't have an entry in the table, it will replace it with an `<img>` tag with  `src="undefined"`.